# Laravel 5.2 filename appending index number

Tags: laravel-5, file-storage

I have simple dilema using **Laravel 5.2**. I want to store files in certain directories. There are 2 steps i need to do:

1. Check if filename is not taken already.
2. If filename is already taken, append index number with dash to filename: `"_1"`

If `"_1"` is already taken, then filename should append `"_2"` etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use simple loop:

```php
$file_name = "file";
$ext = "jpg";
$i = 0;
$original_file_name = $file_name
while (file_exists("{$file_name}.{$ext}")) {
 $i++;
 $file_name = $original_file_name . '_' . $i;
}
```

Comment: I exactly thought of this approach. But isnt iteration of folder and its scanning be performance heavy?

Comment: its depends if its a scenario that is rarely happen, and in 99% of cases there will be no more than 1-3 same file names, than I would not worry too much about 3-4 reads from disk once in a month, I think to make it more performance wise you can you scandir() to list all the files in the directory instead of "blind looping"

Comment: Thanks for your answer!